# What should we do about the [tag:shia-sunni] tag?

Tags: discussion, tag

I personally think that the [shia-sunni](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shia-sunni) tag should not exist on the main site, but since it seems to be used to ask the differences between Sunni and Shiism I think that is a fair reason to keep it.  So I think it should be renamed or something, I saw we have on the main site a tag called [differences](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differences) and thought that we could clean up the "shia-sunni" tag and merge it with the "differences" tag and make it's purpose a bit more clear, but on review of this thought I found that the [differences](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differences) tag is not limited to simply asking the differences between sunni shia, but also between arabic words and different religions.

So what should we do with the [shia-sunni](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shia-sunni) tag?  Of course it needs a bit of cleaning, but should we rename it? If so to what? Should we merge it with another tag? If so then with what tag?

Answer (score 1):

[differences](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differences) could also refer to the differences between the 4 madhabs.

I suggest modifying it to [shia-sunni-differences](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shia-sunni-differences). Long, but makes more sense to new users than the previous tag.

Comment: That would make it more cluttered and redundant.